# Chaining a sequence of actions when communicating in a UI thread

Tags: android, ui-thread

I am designing a small application which changes a `TextView` every second with a random letter.

For now, my code looks like this and works very well :

```
@BindView(R.id.textview_letter) TextView letterTV;
private static final int DELAY_MILLIS = 1000;
private static final int LOOP_MAX = 10;
private static final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

private Handler h = new Handler();
private Random random = new Random();
private int position = 0;

private Runnable run = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (position >= LOOP_MAX) {
            letterTV.setText("THE END !");
            h.removeCallbacks(run);
        } else {
            String randomLetter = String.valueOf(ALPHABET.charAt(random.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
            letterTV.setText(randomLetter);
            h.postDelayed(run, DELAY_MILLIS);
            position++;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mylayout);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    h.post(run);
}
```

I now want to improve it by setting the background of my `TextView` to black (or make it invisible) for few ms between each letter, so the user is notified in case there is twice the same letter in a row.

My only noob thought was to put another `Runnable` in my `Runnable` and handle them with split delay (like 700 and 300 ms for instance), but this seems hugely overcomplicated.

What is the right way to do this ?
(and BTW, is the Runnable/Handler really the most adapted pattern for me to use ?)

**EDIT** : In a non-UI thread I could do domething like this :

```
while (randomLetter.next()) {
    letterTV.setText(randomLetter);
    Thread.sleep(700);
    letterTV.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    Thread.sleep(300);
}
```

Comment: if you want just notify user, you can create a list of color and change the background with this colors each time you set a letter

Comment: Sorry but I think you didn't understood what I wanted to do. Thanks for trying though

Comment: but if 2 same latter happened , colors are different

Comment: Oh sorry, yes this is clever, but not what I want to do.

Comment: also you can use 2 separate Runnable, and nested  is not necessary

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use RxAndroid, it will reduce the complexity:

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Disposable randomLetterObservable;
    private TextView textView;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        randomLetterObservable = Observable.interval(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .timeInterval()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<Timed<Long>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(Timed<Long> longTimed) throws Exception {
                        String randomLetter = String.valueOf(ALPHABET.charAt(random.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
                        textView.setText(randomLetter);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (randomLetterObservable != null) {
            randomLetterObservable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

with dependencies:

```
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.8'
```

**Edit:** Here is a modified solution that also changes the background if the same letter occurs twice in a row.

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Disposable randomLetterObservable;
    private TextView textView;
    private Random random = new Random();
    private final String ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    private String lastLetter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);

        randomLetterObservable = Observable.interval(700L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .timeInterval()
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .switchMap(new Function<Timed<Long>, ObservableSource<String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<String> apply(Timed<Long> longTimed) throws Exception {
                        String randomLetter = String.valueOf(ALPHABET.charAt(random.nextInt(ALPHABET.length())));
                        if (randomLetter.equals(lastLetter)) {
                            textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                            return Observable.just(randomLetter)
                                    .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                                    .debounce(300L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                        } else {
                            lastLetter = randomLetter;
                            return Observable.just(randomLetter);
                        }
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Consumer<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void accept(String s) throws Exception {
                        textView.setText(s);
                        textView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                    }
                });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (randomLetterObservable != null) {
            randomLetterObservable.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Events are emitted in a background thread, background color and letters are set on the main thread. I think this is pretty much what you asked for. (You might need to play with the values to get the desired effect).

Good luck.

Comment: This seems very interesting but your code doesn't compile.

Comment: You have to add the Rx dependencies: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid

Comment: I did, still doesnt compile

Comment: What was the error you were getting? Which Rx versions are you using?

Comment: I get a lot of errors, the first one is `onCompleted()` not been overridable. `TimeInterval` dosen't seems to be found too. I use the latest, as written in the link you just gave.

Comment: You are right, the previous example was for an older Rx version. I updated the code. I actually tested it myself and it worked fine. Give it a try and let me know if you managed to solve it.

Comment: You're welcome. Are you not accepting the answer? Is there still something missing?

Comment: Sorry, this is not me being greedy, but your answer is just a (very) good hint to go on. It tells me how I can do exactly the same I'm doing, maybe with a better way, but it doesn't answer the question about **sequences** of events.

Comment: Rx is all about streams/sequences of events on which you can apply different operators. I added another example with the background change and a brief explanation. I hope this answers your initial question.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you edit. It was perfect, except from `debounce()`, which I switched to `delay()`. Many thanks ! Just a question though, wouldn't be any need to declare some variables as `volatile` ?